# Cannot access https://superuser.com with netscape 3.04

Tags: encryption, website

As specified at the bottom of https://superuser.com/, this website is best on Netscape 3.0.

I tried to access it with but all I have is a nice error : 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsKc1.png)

Comment: Where'd you get netscape 3? Have you tried trying harder? Triple or quadruple click?

Comment: I got it from https://github.com/wycats/nnhistory/tree/master/304/Netscape/Navigator. I tried double-click, triple-click, changing the mouse, the pointer, nothing worked !
I am so SAD !

Comment: Given that the banner mentioning Netscape 3.0 is only visible on the April Fools version of the site it is reasonable to assume that it should not be taken 100% seriously.  [What browsers are officially supported by Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)